# Unity C# - On button click pass gameobject to another C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have multiple buttons with a different gameobject attached to them.
When the button is clicked I want to pass the gameobject to another C# script which will after some conditions instantiate that passed gameobject.
I have this code for the buttons:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Element : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Button btn;
    public GameObject furniture;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        btn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(PassObjectToAnotherScript);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void PassObjectToAnotherScript()
    {
        //Code to pass the object to another C# script
    }
}
```

The C# script to which the gameobject has to be passed to should have a:

```
private GameObject PassedGameObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be as simple as having the second script exposing a field or property that you can pass your object to. One of many ways to do this could look like this:

```
public class Element : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Button btn;
    public GameObject furniture;
    public Receiver recevier;

    void Start ( )
    {
        btn = GetComponent<Button> ( );
        btn.onClick.AddListener ( PassObjectToAnotherScript );
    }

    void PassObjectToAnotherScript ( )
    {
        //Code to pass the object to another C# script
        recevier.PassedGameObject = furniture;
    }
}

public class Receiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _PassedGameObject;
    public GameObject PassedGameObject
    {
        get => _PassedGameObject;
        set
        {
            _PassedGameObject = value;
            Debug.Log ( $"Receiver[{name}] just received \'{_PassedGameObject.name}\'" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Milan thanks for your answer, but I am getting this error in the console:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Element.PassObjectToAnotherScript () (at Assets/Scripts/Element.cs:21)

Comment: @Hamza did you add the Receiver component to an object, then drag that object into the "Receiver" field in the "Element" component?

Comment: thank you verry much. I have done what you replied to me and it worked. I appreciate it a lot.